Definition Homology Theory
In my topology class we defined singular topology in the classical way i.e looking at maps $\sigma: \Delta_n \to X$ forming the singular $n$ complex and taking homology of it (see e.g Bredon). I saw now Algebraic topology with a viewpoint towards homotopy theory by Marcelo Aguilar, Samuel Gitler, Carlos Prieto, a completly different approach. They define for a space $X$ the symmetric Product of $X$ as intuitivly spoken unordered infinit pairs of $X$. then they defined the reduced homology of a CW complex X to be $H_n'(X) = \pi_n(SPX)$ and for a CW pair (X,A) $H_n(X,A) = H_n'(X\cup CA)$. Now I have some questions:

Why does he restrict to CW complexes, this definition would work for arbitrary spaces right?

is this homology theory the same as singular homology for CW complexes and for general topological spaces? If no why not and if yes, is there a nice proof of it. Unlikely the book does not speak about singular homology with Simplicies.(It should be at least for CW complexes the same as in the book it is shown that it fullfilles all the axioms of a homology theory and I have read somewhere that there is up to isomorphie only one such homology theory, but I never saw a proof of it).



The answer to 2. is yes, and this is known as the Dold-Thom theorem. You can find a proof in Hatcher (Theorem 4K.6), although fair warning that it is rather involved. As for 1., the definition is certainly well-formed for general spaces, but perhaps you do not get the right groups out when $X$ is not a CW-complex. I don't know this for sure, but Hatcher's discussion also heavily makes use of simplicial/CW structures, and I think I dimly remember something about symmetric products not being invariant under weak equivalences.

There is a counterexample for non-CW complexes on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dold%E2%80%93Thom_theorem
